# Handling subscription of reused route using RouteReuseStrategy

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular2-observables

I am using **RouteReuseStrategy** for saving the current route when I navigate from Page A to Page B,
when I navigate back from Page B to Page A, I am reusing the saved snapshot of Page A component.

In this particular scenario the Page A subscription is still live due to **RouteReuseStrategy** doesn't destroy the Page A component(**On Destroy** only I unsubscribed all the subscription).

So if I navigate from Page C or D component, I am re-initializing the Page A Component, at that time there will be 2 instances of Page A Component. Due to which the subscription is calling twice.

Is there any way to handle the manual subscription and angular's internal subscriptions for that specific Page A Component and its child Components.